# How to Get the Items Url from Links list

Tags: sharepoint

I have a links list in the site.

ex:

apple----http//:apple.com
nokia----http://nokia.com

I need to get the url of each item and append it to the Html LI and UL elements. 
Is this possible through  object model.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can tell us what language you use first. 
And i suggest if you want get something in a linked list, you should design a good struct

ex.

```
         +----+      +----+
Head ->  |name|  +-> |name|
         +----+  |   +----+
         |url |  |   |url |
         +----+  |   +----+
         |next| -+   |next| -> NULL
         +----+      +----+
```

you can get head->url at first.
then you just move head to next you can get next url.